# Jade variable rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

Folks, 
  How would I access variables that I set in script. ?

```
#someModal.modal.fade.large
 .modal-dialog(style="width:70%")
    .modal-content
        .modal-header
            button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') &times;
            h2.modal-title #{someVariable}
        .modal-body
            h3
               ...

script.
    | var someVariable = #{someVariable};

script.
    $('body').on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        var someVariable = 'test';
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will not start to run until your page has loaded, so jade will never have access to the variables that are set on the client. You should use jQuery to modify the HTML elements instead.

```
script.
    var $modal = $('#someModal')
      , $title = $modal.find('.modal-title');
    $modal.on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        var someVariable = 'test';
        $title.text(someVariable);
    });

    $modal.modal();
```

Comment: This works, thank you!  Question, whats the difference between $('body').on('show.bs.modal', and $('modal').xxx

Comment: How would i find and place text into `span.label.label-info Email
                                                    | ` ? :)

Comment: When you call `.modal()` on an element, only that element will be able to listen to the events associated with that modal (see [line 46](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L46) of the source to see exactly where the `show.bs.modal` event is fired).

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I typically use is just attaching the variable to the window:

```
#someModal.modal.fade.large
 .modal-dialog(style="width:70%")
    .modal-content
        .modal-header
            button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') &times;
            h2.modal-title #{someVariable}
        .modal-body
            h3
               ...
script
  | var someVariable = #{someVariable};
script.
    $('body').on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        var someVariable = 'test';
    });
```

Note that you'll need to `JSON.stringify` the variable if it is an `Object` (or `Array`).

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!
Where would I put your code... in the jade block or the javascript block?  Do you mind adding your solution to my code above? Im super-new at front-end dev.

Comment: You'd want to add this script tag before the script tag that already exists.

Comment: This answer only helps you if you already have the variable saved on the server, but want to access it on the client.